# Running SQL Queries using Shell Script and get back the output in CSV Format

Tags: sql, shell, perl, unix, sh

I want to automate a SQL file which contains multiple SQL queries using shell script and in the same time get their output in a .csv format file.

Also there's a catch! These queries will have some variable part i.e they will change and will depend on user input

For Eg:

```
SELECT NAME, CITY, ADDRESS FROM DATA WHERE COUNTRY = 'USA'
```

Here i don't want it always to be USA.So is there a way i can provide COUNTRY as a user input in Shell Script?

Comment: What SQL server are you using?

Comment: @Mark Hi, its Oracle SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Oracle SQL*Plus Substitution Variables.

SQL script "demo.sql" like that

```
SPOOL some.csv APPEND
set colsep ','
SELECT NAME, CITY, ADDRESS FROM DATA WHERE COUNTRY = '&Country';
SPOOL OFF
```

then run script like that

```
sqlplus -S username/pass @demo.sql
```

you will be prompted to input "Country"

```
Enter value for Country:
```

then type something and press Enter.
SQL was executed and will get some.csv file separated by Comma.

Comment: Thanks! Will Try this and Let you Know